# Why does explain say that it uses type ALL for contests table though contest table has chid as primary key?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Why does explain say that it uses type ALL for contests table though contest table has chid as primary key?

---

```
mysql> explain SELECT contests.chid, contests.diff_level from contests, contest_users where contests.chid=contest_users.chid;          


+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys       | key                 | key_len | ref                           | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contests        | ALL  | PRIMARY             | NULL                | NULL    | NULL                          | 37660 |             | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contest_users   | ref  | contest_users_idx   | contest_users_idx   | 4       | fbtable.contests.chid         |     2 | Using index | 
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> desc contests;
  +------------+------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
  | Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default  | Extra          |
  +------------+------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
  | chid       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL     | auto_increment | 
  | puzzle     | char(81)         | YES  |     | NULL     |                | 
  | solution   | char(81)         | YES  |     | NULL     |                | 
  | isComplete | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 0        |                | 
  | diff_level | char(7)          | YES  |     | NULL     |                | 
  | time       | time             | YES  |     | 00:00:00 |                | 
  +------------+------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
  6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> desc contest_users;
  +------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | Field      | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
  +------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | chid       | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       | 
  | uid        | bigint(20) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
  | gamestate  | char(81)             | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
  | score      | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | 0       |       | 
  | no_correct | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       | 
  | no_wrong   | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       | 
  | time       | time                 | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
  | isComplete | tinyint(1)           | YES  |     | 0       |       | 
  +------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess, because there are very few rows.

The query optimizer will probably make different decisions when you have many thousands of rows.

Answer (score 0):

My (late) advice is to add a key on contests table, it has to include the column used for join (chid) **and** also the columns you want from that query.

This will cause mysql to actually use the index to get the data instead of scanning the whole table (type="index", extra="use index" in explain result).

Since chid is in the resultset and also in the join condition, in your case it will look like this:

```
alter table contests add key `chid_diffLevel` (chid, diff_level);
```

I hope it works for you. I've tried it on one of my databases and I know it works for me.